# Basic CSS Style Sheet

Tags: css, image, stack, width

I am having trouble for a project I am working on. I have been requested to do the following:
A. All content should be stacked at smallest screen size, and images should be full-width
B. At 600px wide, "navigation" should be on the left, and "content" on the right
C. At 800px wide, all images should float to the right and should not exceed 40% of the contents width

For A, I believe stacked is default for small screens, and then I am unsure about full-width image?
For B, is it simply float function?
For C, I don't know what it means by "should not exceed 40%..."

This is my current code:

```
@media screen {
  img{width:100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
  nav{float: left;}
  div{float: right;}
}
  @media only screen and (min-width:800px){
```

Answer (score 0):

*You are asking about*: **At 800px wide**, all images should float to the right and should not exceed 40% of the contents width ?

from your statement, the content width then is 800px wide. and that means that:

```
1. image has property float with right value.
2. image width should not be more than 40% of the content width (800px).
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) comes to mind when I think of the easiest way to handle the requirements you detailed.

A. The smallest screen size having all content stacked is already handled for you.  Including pictures full width.  Just keep the pictures, and content, that should be stacked in it's own column, and set widths on the pictures.

B. The Navigation can easily be in the left column, content in the right column, by using the predefined Bootstrap Grid classes of ".col-sm-5" for the left, and "col-sm-7", for example.

C.  I would just set the float right with a percentage as the size for the pictures at the given screen size. i.e. min-width:800px / image width:60%, or if the content will wrap around the images, you could place them in an inner grid.

(Note: You will have to slightly customize the pixel widths that define the screen size you want, but it will get you heading in the right direction)

I would set up a simple grid with the pieces you want and play around with the columns and widths, you can test by re-sizing your browser and seeing how the columns and rows adjust.

Not only will you be able to get the requirements met, but you will also have a lot of additional features that could help with future scope creep requests.